# Getting distance between point and line with specific values?

Tags: postgis, query, st-distance

I have a table named `"housenumbers"` that contains points with addresses fields, and one of them is `"street_name"`. And I also have another table named `"streets"`, that contains lines that are the geometries of roads, and a field that contains its `"name"`.

I need to get the distance from each point to the nearest street that has the same street name.

Up to now, I have this:

```sql
select st_distance(housenumbers.geom,streets.geom),*
from housenumbers, streets
where housenumbers.street_name = streets.name
```

It's working, but it's showing all the distances from each point to all streets with the same name in the area. What I need is only the nearest one.

Comment: search among the top posts in [tag:knn] related to PostGIS; you'd only need to add `WHERE <housenumbers>.street_name = <streets>.name` to the `LATERAL` subquery. if you get stuck, edit your question with the details of your issue